# Confusion about terms involving varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm sure there is a very simple explanation for my confusion but I can't seem to figure it out. I am reading some notes online being a simple introduction to algebraic geometry and a variety is defined as being an irreducible algebraic subset (of either affine or projective space). It defines the Zariski topology on affine / projective space by stating that the closed sets are precisely given by the algebraic subsets, which is fine. But later down the road it refers as an example ${X = \mathbb{A}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}}$ as an open subvariety of ${\mathbb{A}^2}$: I can see this is clearly an open subset in the Zariski topology since ${\{(0,0)\}}$ is clearly a variety,  but why is $X$ called a subvariety since it is very much not a variety?

EDIT: as pointed out I should of course mention which notes I'm following: [https://dept.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf](https://dept.math.lsa.umich.edu/%7Ewfulton/CurveBook.pdf).

Comment: When you write about some text, mention (and, if possible, link to) the text.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Of course, apologies. I've added it in the post now. Thank you!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez But then in chapter 2, a variety is defined as an irreducible algebraic set, which is not an open subset of a closed set. I guess my confusion is that these definitions seem a little contradictory unless I'm missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the beginning of chapter 6.2, a variety is defined as an open subset of a closed irreducible set of affine or projective space. Therefore open subsets of varieties are also varieties.

There is a more abstract definition of variety that some other textbooks use: a variety is an integral separated scheme of finite type over a field. Under this definition, an open subset of a variety is also a variety.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In chapter 2, a variety is also defined as an irreducible algebraic set, which is not an open subset of a closed set. My confusion is that these definitions seem a little contradictory unless I'm missing something?

Comment: The definition in chapter 2 is for **affine** varieties. There are varieties that are not affine, such as the example you gave.